# Error occurs when show a picture in Qlabel

Tags: qt

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDialog>
#include <opencv2\video\video.hpp>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QScrollBar>
cv::Mat image1;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
image1 = cv::imread("D:\\picture.jpg");
QImage       qimage1((uchar*)image1.data,image1.cols,image1.rows,image1.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimage1));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

I have picture with size 720*1280. I want to show this picture in label with size 600*600. However,it only shows a part of the picture. So my question is how to show entire picture without changing the size of picture.

Comment: Why are you loading the image using opencv? Have you checked that the created image contains all the data you expect? For example, save the image to file: `qimage1.save("D:/picture-saved.jpg")`

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to rescale the image to size 600*600 or not? You cannot show an image with size 720*1280 as 600*600 "without changing the size of picture".

Comment: I want to use Scroll bar but i don't know how to add it in label

Answer (score 3):

You can use function `QPixmap::scaled()`, see docs [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qpixmap.html#scaled) and examples [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Scaling_QPixmap_image)

In your case it would be something like this:

```
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimage1).scaled(QSize(600,600), Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

It won't affect the image itself, it will construct QPixmap from the image, scale it to fit your 600x600 Qlabel and will keep aspect ration. Hope this will help you. By the way, you don't need yo use OpenCV to just read an image, in Qt `QImage` class can construct QImage with just QString path_to_image: `QImage myImg("D:\\picture.jpg");`

EDITED (sorry for the delay):

To add QScrollArea, you have to create it in constructor (let's assume, that in your Mainwindow you have only QLabel and QScrollArea) like this:

```
// constructor, right after ui->setupUi(this);
QScrollArea *scroll=new QScrollArea(this); // creating instance of QScrollarea with mainwindow as it's parent
scroll->setWidget(ui->label); // sets widget, that you want to have scrollbars
this->setCentralWidget(scroll); // sets scrollarea as centralwidget
```

Comment: I want to use Scroll bar but i don't know how to add it in label